# Excel: most descending/ascending consecutive points

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to calculate a consecutive descending or ascending pattern.

Example for this set of points:

1 4 8 26 16 7 2 1 8 10

The formula result should be 5, since 26>16>7>2>1 is the most numbers in descending order in a row.

Can someone help?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: So are they in a range? Please post some samples and your tries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Maximum of Consecutive Descending Data Points

**Readable**

```
=LET(data,A1:T1,
    ds,HSTACK(INDEX(data,1),DROP(data,,-1)),
    tf,data<ds,
1+MAX(SCAN(0,tf,LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r,rr+1,0)))))
```

**Short**

```
=LET(data,A1:T1,
1+MAX(SCAN(0,data<HSTACK(INDEX(data,1),DROP(data,,-1)),
    LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r,rr+1,0)))))
```

[image]

**Helper Formulas**

```
A1  =SORTBY(SEQUENCE(,20),RANDARRAY(,20))
A2  =HSTACK(A1,DROP(A1:T1,,-1))
A3  =(A1:T1)<(A2#)
A4  =SCAN(0,A3#,LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r,rr+1,0)))
```

### Edit ('Final Answer')

- Since there is no use of the first element, applying the logic from **user11222393**'s (and **P.b**'s) answer, it boils down to:

```
=LET(data,A1:T1,
1+MAX(SCAN(0,DROP(data,,1)<DROP(data,,-1),
    LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r,rr+1,0)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Value is never *1*. Either *0* or *>1*.

To count max descending:

```
=LET(z,MAX(SCAN(0,A1:A9>A2:A10,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b=TRUE,a+1,0)))),IF(z<>0,z+1,z))
```

To count max ascending:

```
=LET(z,MAX(SCAN(0,A1:A9<A2:A10,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b=TRUE,a+1,0)))),IF(z<>0,z+1,z))
```

Result:

[image]

Note: for formula to work correctly all values in range `A1:A10` must be filled.

Comment: Great! I thought I didn't care about the 0-1 issue and abandoned it. After putting it into words *"There can be 0 or more than one data point!"*, I do.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I didn't care at first too! Until I almost accidently got sequence of 10 *1's* to test with, getting wrong answer 1 for both ascending and descending!

Answer (score 2):

```
=LET(a,A1:A10,
     d,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)-1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(INDEX(a,y)>INDEX(a,y+1),x+1,0))),
     u,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)-1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(INDEX(a,y)<INDEX(a,y+1),x+1,0))),
MAX(d,u)+1)
```

Or in older excel:

```
=MAX(
     FREQUENCY(
               IF((A1:A9>A2:A10),ROW(A1:A9)),
               IF((A1:A9<A2:A10),ROW(A1:A9))),
     FREQUENCY(
               IF((A1:A9<A2:A10),ROW(A1:A9)),
               IF((A1:A9>A2:A10),ROW(A1:A9)))
     )+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Challenged myself to do ascending and descending in one iteration:

```
=LET(data,B1:K1,
signs,SIGN(DROP(data,,1)-DROP(data,,-1)),
runs,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(signs)),LAMBDA(a,I,LET(prev,SIGN(a),curr,INDEX(signs,I),IFS(curr=0,0,curr=prev,a+curr,TRUE,2*curr)))),
MAX(ABS(runs)))
```

[image]

Comment: I like it when you're feeling challenged.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use some helper columns?

One helper column verifies if the numbers are ascending (value '1') or not (value '-1').
The next helper column takes the number of equal values and starts back at 1 when another value is found.
The third helper column takes the maximum of the second helper column and adds 1, leading to the result.

Hereby a screenshot with some formulae, but beware: the formula in column "C" only starts at "C3", cell "C2" simply equals `=B2`:

[image]